# How to make cursor at the right side of the hint inside a EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

[image]I have tried all the methods I can find but none of them works.

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/rrValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxWidth="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:hint="why the cursor always on my left?"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"/>
```

Comment: And you want the text to be on the left? And the cursor on the right??

Comment: Exactly I want the hint to be on the left and the cursor on the right when the EditText get focus. Now the cursor is always on the left.

Comment: The hint is supposed to be overwritten.

Comment: Because the hint is that, a hint. It does not stay. It is not designed to do that.

Comment: I know it is supposed to be overwritten, but I hope the cursor will be at the end not at the start position. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this add a new TextView exactly behind your EditText and set it's text to the hint's text. Here is code for that:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/rrValue"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxWidth="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:background="#a2b3c4"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="7dp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:text="why the cursor always on my left?"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="7dp"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your Activity class you need to add TextChangedListener and hide text view is no text is present in Edit Text:

```
EditText rrValue  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.rrValue);
    final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    rrValue.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(s.length()>0){
                tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else
            {
                tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


        }
    });
```